# Variables in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

Assume I have the following SCSS file content:

```
#id1 .class1 {
  input {
    padding: 4px;
    border: 0px none;
    &:disabled {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}

// .... other scss settings

.class2 #id2 .class3 {
  input {
    padding: 4px;
    border: 0px none;
    &:disabled {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

As you notice that there are repeated definition. So basically how can I do write the following pseudo-code

```
$var1: input {
          padding: 4px;
          border: 0px none;
          &:disabled {
            color: red;
          }
        }

#id1 .class1 {
  $var1
}

// .... other scss settings

.class2 #id2 .class3 {
  $var1
}
```

Is it possible to do that somehow?

Comment: `#id1 .class1, .class2 #id2 .class3 {` Also, id's must be unique across a page, so `.class2 #id2 .class3` can be reduced to `#id2 .class3`.

Comment: @Ouroborus - Thanks for pointing this out. I just wrote this on the go, without thinking. I even voted you up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [`@mixin`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin/):

```scss
@mixin withInputStyles() {
  input {
    padding: 4px;
    border: 0px none;
    &:disabled {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}

#id1 .class1 {
  @include withInputStyles;
}

.class2 #id2 .class3 {
  @include withInputStyles;
}
```

**CSS output**

```css
#id1 .class1 input {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 0px none;
}
#id1 .class1 input:disabled {
  color: red;
}

.class2 #id2 .class3 input {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 0px none;
}
.class2 #id2 .class3 input:disabled {
  color: red;
}
```

---

If you don't want the styles to be duplicated, another possibility is to use [`@extend`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend/) and a [placeholder selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors/):

```scss
%inputStyles {
  input {
    padding: 4px;
    border: 0px none;
    &:disabled {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}

#id1 .class1 {
  @extend %inputStyles;
}

.class2 #id2 .class3 {
  @extend %inputStyles;
}
```

**CSS output**

```css
.class2 #id2 .class3 input, #id1 .class1 input {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 0px none;
}
.class2 #id2 .class3 input:disabled, #id1 .class1 input:disabled {
  color: red;
}
```